# Select tag in Angular not showing Placeholder when adding *ngFor

Tags: angular, select

The placeholder suddenly disappears when I add a for loop to my select options.

This code will show the placeholder:

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6" *ngIf="businessForm">
                <div class="form-group mb-3">
                    <select name="jobType" formControlName="jobType" class="form-control ps-1">
                        <option hidden value="" [disabled]="true" [selected]="true">Placeholder</option>
                        <!-- <option *ngFor="let jobType of jobTypes" value="{{jobType}}">{{jobType}}</option> -->
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
```

This code will not show the placeholder:

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6" *ngIf="businessForm">
                <div class="form-group mb-3">
                    <select name="jobType" formControlName="jobType" class="form-control ps-1">
                        <option hidden value="" [disabled]="true" [selected]="true">Placeholder</option>
                        <option *ngFor="let jobType of jobTypes" value="{{jobType}}">{{jobType}}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
```

All I did was uncomment one line of code.